# VREF and COMP pins for a UC3845

Tags: power-supply, datasheet

This is [uc3845](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/uc3844-d.pdf) IC which use for control PWM in power supply.
I see this set up on datasheet for testing and I want to set up this on breadboard for better understanding how this IC work, but I don’t know VREF voltage. How much voltage VREF should have?
Regards.

Plus, I don't know COMP pin use for, can anyone explain it to me?

[image]

Comment: This is explained in the datasheet. You can search for "VREF" in the PDF and read all the relevant paragraphs. If something is not clear you can ask a specific question here :)

Comment: Word of warning: that thing switches at up to 500 kHz, that's relatively fast. A breadboard might bring a lot of parasitic capacitance that might make things work differently than predicted.

Comment: Switchers are really bad news on breadboards…

Comment: If you want to experiment with a switching regulator, try the MC34063 -- it's like the 555 of the switching regulators, old but still widely used. You might even find one in a car USB charger adapter. You'll easily find video tutorials on it like [(here)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txvqJRyYZBY) and [(here)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGp82xhybs4), for instance.

Comment: @MarcusMüller As a read through of the datasheet (page 9 in particular) would make even more clear..! :)

Comment: @awjlogan uff, yes, the wording is pretty clear. Maybe you want to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

> how much voltage VREF should have

VREF for the UC3845 is 5V. It is set by the chip, not your circuit.

> plus, i dont know COMP pin use for, can anyone explain me ?

Figures 20, 21, 22 and 29 of the [ONSEMI datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/uc3844-d.pdf) show a couple of uses of the COMP pin.

Also see Figure 8 and page 6 of the [Fairchild datasheet](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/fairchild/UC3842.pdf) for an additional shutdown mechanism.

The TI application report [AN-1286 Compensation for the LM3478 Boost Controller](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva067c/snva067c.pdf) contains an in-depth discussion of the theory behind the compensation network shown in Figure 29.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to use this IC on a breadboard, have a look at page 9 in the [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/uc3844-d.pdf). It is *very* clear that you should not try to do this:

> **Do not attempt to construct the converter on wire−wrap or plug−in prototype boards.**

Emphasis theirs :) The chances are it will not work due to the breadboard's parasitics, and you won't get any insight into it at all.

Comment: Note that the OP's circuit is not a power converter. It looks like the UCx842 is being used as some sort of PWM generator or something like that.